# Updating Mongo documents through node but no results

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've been trying to add emails (which is a new field) to my "people" collection but I don't know why I'm getting no results from the server. This is my code

```
for (key in D_emails) {
  console.log(D_emails[key])
  try {
    o_id = new mongo.ObjectID(D_emails[key])

    collection.updateOne({
      _id: o_id
    }, {
      $set: {
        "Email": key
      }
    }, function(err, results) {
      if (err) {
        throw err
      } else if (results.length) {
        console.log(results)
      } else {
        console.log("no results")
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: D_emails is a dictionary with the emails for its key and mongo documents _id for its values. I made this way just to make sure there's no duplication in the emails.

Comment: what is the value of `results` ?

Answer (score 4):

According to mongo documentation for [updateOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/) the response of the query (`results` in your case) does not contain length element and it is not an array or an object. This will be the response according to the documentation:

Returns a document containing:

> - A boolean `acknowledged` as `true` if the operation ran with write    concern or `false` if write concern was disabled
> - `matchedCount` containing the number of matched documents
> - `modifiedCount` the number of modified documents
> - `upsertedId` containing the `_id` for the upserted document

Answer (score 1):

first of all. try to code without try catch blocks when using the concept of "err" object being returned from every asynchronous callback. You can treat the error right inside the callback. "throwing" the error will also prevent other emails from being updated. But maybe that's what you want. It doesn't really matter now.

Now, back to your question. let me show you what `result` is, in this example:

```
// inserting.
collection.insertOne({_id: "lala", a:10, b:20}, function (err, r) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    assert.equal(1, r.insertedCount);

    // updating.
    collection.updateOne({_id: "lala"}, {$set: {a: 99}}, {}, function(err, result) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        console.log(result) // first thing printed.
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, "\t")) // second print.

        // checking whats inside it.
        collection.findOne({_id: "lala"}, {}, function(err, doc) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            console.log(doc) // third print.

            db.close() // don't close connection if you don't need to.
        })
    })
})
```

the 3 printed things will be (scroll to the end to see what you actually want):

```
CommandResult {
  result: { ok: 1, nModified: 1, n: 1 },
  connection: 
   Connection {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { close: [Object],
        error: [Object],
        timeout: [Object],
        parseError: [Object],
        connect: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 5,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     options: 
      { socketOptions: {},
        auto_reconnect: true,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        cursorFactory: [Object],
        reconnect: true,
        emitError: true,
        size: 5,
        disconnectHandler: [Object],
        bson: BSON {},
        messageHandler: [Function],
        wireProtocolHandler: [Object] },
     id: 1,
     logger: Logger { className: 'Connection' },
     bson: BSON {},
     tag: undefined,
     messageHandler: [Function],
     maxBsonMessageSize: 67108864,
     port: 27017,
     host: 'localhost',
     keepAlive: true,
     keepAliveInitialDelay: 0,
     noDelay: true,
     connectionTimeout: 0,
     socketTimeout: 0,
     destroyed: false,
     domainSocket: false,
     singleBufferSerializtion: true,
     serializationFunction: 'toBinUnified',
     ca: null,
     cert: null,
     key: null,
     passphrase: null,
     ssl: false,
     rejectUnauthorized: false,
     checkServerIdentity: true,
     responseOptions: { promoteLongs: true },
     flushing: false,
     queue: [],
     connection: 
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'localhost',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 8,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        destroyed: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 334,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: null,
        _server: null,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true },
     writeStream: null,
     hashedName: '29bafad3b32b11dc7ce934204952515ea5984b3c',
     buffer: null,
     sizeOfMessage: 0,
     bytesRead: 0,
     stubBuffer: null },
  matchedCount: 1,
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0 }
{
    "ok": 1,
    "nModified": 1,
    "n": 1
}
{ _id: 'lala', a: 99, b: 20 }
```

the first object is the `result` returned from "updateOne()".
the second object is the `result`'s "toString()" implementation and this is what's inside `result.result` (scroll back to top).
the last object is what I get after querying for the updated document.

you can find more examples on the native mongodb driver for nodejs website: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#updateOne
their are full of examples.